# Que signifie le mot «tergiversation» dans ce contexte?

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour à tous. Que signifie le mot «tergiversation» dans ce contexte:

> La première pièce théâtrale sur la fête des moutons a connu un grand succès à l'étranger, mais au Maroc, cela a été le blackout. Et après une seule représentation, la deuxième pièce théâtrale sur la vie et la mort d’un ancien philosophe arabe du Xe siècle a disparu mystérieusement du circuit. Il semble bien qu’il y ait patrimoine et patrimoine, au moins dans la demande, ou dans la manière dont sont reçues ou non les tentatives d’utilisation de la tradition historique ou littéraire ancienne. Nous jugeons qu’en l’absence d’une formule d’équilibre, par définition personnelle, cette tergiversation hétérogène des codes culturels peut être vécue sur le mode particulier et donne une dimension dramatique à la vie. Cette tergiversation « risque de se transformer en mouvement implosif, dans le retrait de ses formes imaginaires et dans son activité réelle ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le texte que vous citez me semble assez clair au début. A partir de "Nous jugeons", où l'auteur parle sans doute au nom d'un collectif ou d'un groupe constitué, cela relève du langage codé et ressort à mon avis du jargon du groupe en question.

Le terme tergiversation qui vous intéresse me semble utilisé de manière assez peu pertinente dans ce texte : la tergiversation est constituée par une suite d'hésitations qui ne semble pas décrite par le processus critiqué dans le texte, processus qui a purement et simplement abouti à la disparition de la pièce du circuit. Il faut sans doute comprendre que les auteurs du texte préfèrent utiliser le terme de tergiversation comme un euphémisme d'"interdiction" ou de "censure", des mots plus crus et sans doute plus proches de la réalité, mais qui exposeraient probablement les auteurs à des représailles. La dernière phrase est poétique, mais hermétique.

Answer (score 1):

J'ajouterais qu'au-delà de la question de la censure informelle, je crois que l'on fait ici allusion à l'idée qu'il y aurait deux poids, deux mesures dans l'évaluation ou la définition du patrimoine culturel.

Comment: Merci énormément